# How to plot multiple time series data over multiple iterations onto a pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a time series data set similar to the one created in the code below. There are three `ID` (individuals) in each `State`, and there are three variables for each `ID`. For each `Var` within each `State`, I need a single line plot containing that states individuals. The example below shows how I have been accomplishing this using Florida and Georgia as an example. How can I simplify this task, telling R to do it for each `Var` in each `State`? Also, what is the best way to automatically paste the plots to a PDF file?

```r
 State <- rep(c("FL", "GA", "SC", "NC"), each = 400)
ID <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"), 
          times = c(150,150,100,150,150,100,150,150,100, 150,150,100))
Time <- rep(c(1:150, 1:150, 1:100), times = 4)
Var1 <- rnorm(1600)
Var2 <- rnorm(1600)
Var3 <- rnorm(1600)
data <- data.frame(cbind(State, ID, Time, Var1, Var2, Var3))
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_minimal())

#i need to plot these by state so i subset each state and plot:

Florida <- data %>%
  filter(State == "FL")
Georgia <- data %>%
  filter(State == "GA")

ggplot(Florida, aes(x = Time, y = Var1))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
  theme_minimal()
ggplot(Florida, aes(x = Time, y = Var2))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
  theme_minimal()
ggplot(Florida, aes(x = Time, y = Var3))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
  theme_minimal()
ggplot(Georgia, aes(x = Time, y = Var1))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
  theme_minimal()
ggplot(Georgia, aes(x = Time, y = Var2))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
  theme_minimal()
ggplot(Georgia, aes(x = Time, y = Var3))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach for this kind of thing is to reshape the data so that each of the variables you want to send to a ggplot2 aesthetic is in a separate column of the data. In this case, State is one variable (which we can keep as-is) and the choice of Var1/Var2/Var3 is another, which we can map to a key-value pair using `tidyr::pivot_longer` (an updated incarnation of `tidyr::gather`).

#### Single page "small multiples" version (`ggplot2` alone)

`ggplot2` is typically used to create a single-page figure, so in this case the plots will be shown as small multiples in a grid.

```
library(tidyverse)
# When I ran the code in the question, Var1-Var3 came in as character strings, not numeric as intended.
data <- tibble(State, ID, Time, Var1, Var2, Var3)
theme_set(theme_minimal())

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(State:Time), names_to = "Stat", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Value))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_grid(Stat~State)

ggsave("my_plots.pdf", path = save_dir, width=10, height=6, dpi=600, device = cairo_pdf)
```

[image]

#### Multi page version with common legend (`ggplot2` + `ggforce`)

If you want all the plots on their own pages, you can achieve this using a loop and `ggforce:facet_grid_paginate`. This implementation will show an all-inclusive legend relating to all the charts. (ie every chart will have a legend showing every ID, even if only some are present in that particular chart.) To avoid that, I think you need to define a plotting function and run your inputs through it (see bottom).

```
pdf("~/my_plots.pdf")
for(i in 1:12) {
  print(my_plots +
    ggforce::facet_grid_paginate(Stat~State, ncol = 1, nrow = 1, page = i))
}
dev.off()
```

#### Multi page version with separate legends (`ggplot2` + custom function)

If you want each plot to print independently, with its own legend, you can make a function that prints a given specification and then send the various inputs into that function.

```
my_state_plot <- function(State_name, Var_name) {
  data %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(State:Time), names_to = "Stat", values_to = "Value") %>%
    filter(State == State_name,
           Stat == Var_name) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Value))+
    geom_line(aes(color = ID), size = 1)+
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = paste(Var_name, "in", State_name))
}
# For example
my_state_plot("FL", "Var1")
```

Here you could pick certain plot combinations and express the order you want. In this case, I'm picking to show Var1 for each State, then Var2, etc. for all State/Var combinations.

```
pdf("~/my_plots.pdf")
crossing(State_name = data$State, 
         Stat = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")) %>%
  pmap(~my_state_plot(..1, ..2)) %>%
  print()
dev.off()
```

Comment: your last example does exactly what I need it to do, except it prints in R. Could you demonstrate the appropriate way to do it using your last example. The code below is what I tried, but does not work <br/> ```r VarsInStates<- <br/> crossing(State_name = data$State, <br/> Stat = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")) <br/> pmap(~my_state_plot(..1, ..2)) <br/> pdf("NewPlots.pdf") <br/> for(I in 1:12){ <br/> print(VarsInStates)+ <br/> ggforce::facet_grid_paginate(Stat~State, ncol = 1, nrow = 1, page = i))} <br/>  dev.off()```

Comment: I do apologize for changing that comment so much I am trying to add line breaks (I am new to the site)

Comment: Edited my answer to add the same pdf printing as the 2nd example.